# How to mock iterator method of JsonArray using mockito and powermockito

Tags: java, mockito, powermockito

I wan to mock iterator function of JsonArray object. `JsonArray` is a custom final class that its iterator function returns an `Iterator<JsonElement>` . Here is what I have tried

```
JsonElement row = ["City1","Date1","Expense1"];
JsonArray jsonArray = row.getAsJsonArray();
final Iterator<JsonElement> iterator = jsonArray.iterator();
JsonElement entry = iterator.next();
if (entry == null || entry.isJsonNull()) {
    return null;
}
```

I want to mock iterator in a way that the entry becomes null.
here is what I have tried but when I debug I see that iterator still works as if not being mocked.

```
Iterator iterator = Mockito.mock(Iterator.class);
PowerMockito.when(iterator.next()).thenReturn(null);
```

Comment: Maybe it makes sense to add some context, for example as to why it's necessary to mock `jsonArray.iterator()` at all.

Answer (score 1):

Can the method you are testing take `row` as an argument? (it looks like it ought to)

Then you can just call it with `[null]` instead of mocking.